# Send email with attachment using AWS SES: run with success but not arrive email to receiver

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, email-attachments, amazon-ses

I'm using a script in python to send emails through AWS SES; first I'm testing in local mode, and later will be deploy in AWS Lambda.

My code is this

```
import boto3
import csv
import os
import datetime as dt
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import mimetypes
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
import base64


def send_email_with_attachment(service, message_text, email_sender, email_receiver, email_cc, 
                                subject, file_attachments: None, image_file_paths: None):
    global mimeMessage
    mimeMessage = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    mimeMessage['to'] = email_receiver
    mimeMessage['from'] = email_sender
    mimeMessage['cc'] = email_cc
    mimeMessage['subject'] = subject
    mimeMessage.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'html'))

    if image_file_paths:
        for i, image_file_path in enumerate(image_file_paths):
            try:
                # Add the image to the email
                image = MIMEImage(open(image_file_path, 'rb').read())
                image.add_header('Content-ID', f'<image{i + 1}>')
                mimeMessage.attach(image)
            except:
                print(f"File path not loaded: {image_file_path}")
                pass

    if file_attachments:
        for attachment in file_attachments:
            # content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(attachment)
            # main_type, sub_type = 'application/octet-stream'.split('/', 1)#content_type.split('/', 1)
            file_name = os.path.basename(attachment)
            
            # with open(attachment, 'rb') as f:
                # myFile = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
                # myFile.set_payload(f.read())
                # myFile.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename = file_name)
                # # encoders.encode_base64(myFile)
            
            attachment_file = open(attachment, 'rb')
            attachment_content = base64.b64encode(attachment_file.read()).decode('utf-8') #Using just if help, because I'm trying to read CSVs files with text in Spanish
            myFile = MIMEApplication(attachment_content)
            myFile.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=file_name)

            mimeMessage.attach(myFile)
    
    message = service.send_raw_email(
            Source = email_sender,
            Destinations = list(map(str.strip, email_receiver.split(','))),
            RawMessage = {
                'Data': mimeMessage.as_string()
            }
        )
    print(f"MESSAGE: {message}")

message = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
            <body>
                TEXT
                
            </body>
    </html>
"""
email_sender = 'sender@outlook.com'
email_receiver = 'reciever@outlook.com'
email_cc = ''
subject = 'subject'
attchment = ['./tmp/file.csv']

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
ses = session.client('ses', region_name='us-east-2')

send_email_with_attachment(ses, message, email_sender, email_receiver, email_cc, 
                            subject, attchment, None)
```

First, when I don't use the file_attachments neither image_file_paths parameters (email with just text), it works fine and email arrive to receiver; but when I add those parameters the code runs with success (this is weird) but email don't arrive to receiver.

Also I've been looking in AWS docs where I found this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-raw.html) that I'm sure is quite similar to mine, but I have the problem described before.

Additional information: already did SES Sender Identity Verification and currently out of the SES sandbox.